# Python Code to Pass Variable to another Python executable and return output

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python code that uses subprocess to open another python file that has been converted to an executable file.  I want to be able to pass a string in the form of a SQL query like SELECT * FROM TABLE.

So I have created a variable string called PARAM that has the value "SELECT * FROM TABLE".

This is the .py making running the subprocess:

```
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
import re
param = "Select * from Table"
send = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Users\\example\\Desktop\\testing.exe",param],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode()
print(send)
```

However for some reason I do not get back the output from the .py file that has been made in to an executable.

Here is the code for the executable:

```
from sys import argv
import requests as rq
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, OPTIONAL


def get_hypercube(query):
    #param =  "select 1 as Id, 'Test' as Name" #argv

    url = 'https://example.com/csv/query'
    kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL, delegate=True)

    payload = "q=" + str(query)
    r = rq.get(url, auth=kerberos_auth, params=payload, verify=False)
    output = r.text

    return output


result = get_hypercube(argv)
print(result)
```

But the send does not bring me the result of the exe file (RESULT).  I must be missing something, or not fully understanding how subprocess works.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't read everything.  Make your programs filters.  Your 1st program should return data that the 2nd program takes as input and filter via pipes

Comment: First program is just passing on the sql string for the second program to run against a server.  The issue is that the output is not being pulled back in to the application.  The reason we need to do this is the python environment we are running does not have all the libraries hence the need for the exe to run and deliver the output back to the first code.

Comment: Send me full code via email to spam@lucasanss.xyz

Comment: Edited to include the first .py running the subprocess